# Why Does Unepxected Error Show in Concrete5 After Pushing Live?

Tags: php, error-handling, concrete5

I just moved my Concrete5 site over from a test server to the live server. However, now I am having problems adding pages. When I click "add blank page" I get the following error:

> An unexpected error occurred. Call to a member function
>   setPageTypeComposerFormLayoutSetControlObject() on a non-object

I have moved the site previously (twice actually) with no issue, but this has popped up since going live yesterday. Not sure even where to begin seeing that I haven't taken a good hard look at Concrete. What should I do to rectify the problem? Any thoughts would be most helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Did you change the site.php with the new database?

Comment: Hi Dannn, the site.php files are different with my version of Concrete. I'm running the latest version (5.7.2.1). They do not require any changes upon moving servers. Only the database.php files need to be edited as well as the .htaccess if necessary.